# Asking for a walk-through/tutorial

Tags: support, specific-question

I just voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/is-there-a-walkthrough-for-implementing-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap), which is asking for a walk-through. I did this because I believe that questions that are asking for *offsite* tuts/walkthroughs are explicitly off-topic, and if they are asking for an onsite one they are too broad. But this particular question does not have any close votes but mine as of now, and it has massive number of views and more than an average of upvotes. Did I go wrong here? Is this question an exempt from the rule? Did I misunderstand the rules?

Comment: I think it just needs to be edited from "Is there a walkthrough for doing X with Y?" into "How do I do X with Y?".  The first answer does feel a little blog-post-y in tone, with some watermarked images (which I guess counts as attribution?), and may also be due for edits by someone familiar with the technology.

Comment: The large number of views/votes is most likely to do with the bounty of 100 rep that was offered.

Comment: @worldofjr: And bountied questions cannot be close-voted, either, making it that much more difficult to rack up any of those.

Comment: In these cases you can also hop in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room and ask the regulars to have a look and offer advice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I edited to question to say:

> How to implement a theme from bootswatch or wrapbootstrap in an MVC 5 project?

rather than:

> Is there a walkthrough for implementing a theme from bootswatch or wrapbootstrap in an MVC 5 project?

IMO that makes it on-topic (before it wasn't). The accepted answer still seems to fit this question and will still be valuable to the community.

---

There are *lots* of questions that are currently open but are actually off-topic. Don't be disheartened that the question is open and has no close votes - once you apply the first vote it will join the close-vote queue and be seen (and voted on) by moderators. :)

Comment: You mean by moderators, users with moderation privileges, not diamonds, right? Because close votes are primarily seen by 3K-ers. Those votes don't end-up in the mod-queue.

Comment: @rene what is the difference between mods and diamonds?

Comment: @Computer_ACE The Stack Exchange network is primarily moderated by the community.  As you gain reputation (and therefore in theory experience in how the site works), you [gain access to various privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), such as voting to close questions etc.  However, there are still certain times where [site moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), indicated by diamonds next to their names, are required to step in and take actions that community members are unable to do themselves.